# iOS Swift - Multiple UITextFields moving UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextfield

First I will describe the layout:
I have a UIView with two UITextfields.  When I select either of the textfields I want the UIView to move up such that the textfields are not covered by the keyboards.  The normal solution is obvious and already implemented: `keyboardWillHide` and `keyboardWillShow`. When i select one textfield the UIView behaves as expect, HOWEVER when I have one textfield selected and then the next textfield is selected the UIVIEW snaps back to the original constraints, and will not readjust, even when `keyboardWillShow` is called again.

How can i achieve the desired effect: When a textfield is selected the UIView moves up, then when the next textfield is selected the UIView remains in the exact same raised position.

Why does the UIView reset on the second textfield being selected currently?

Below is the relevant code, these functions are setup in the VDL.  No other code touches the textfields.  It is worth mentioning these textfields occur in a modal view over current context.  Also worth mentioning the keyboards are of type `decimalPad`

```
// MARK: - keyboard Controls

func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {
    print("Keyboard show")
    if isKeyboardOffset == false {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            print("Keyboard show... \(keyboardSize)")

            self.viewToMove.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height / 2

        }
        isKeyboardOffset = true
    }
}



func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification) {
    print("Keyboard hide")
    if isKeyboardOffset == true {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            print("keyboard hide...")

            self.viewToMove.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height / 2

        }
        isKeyboardOffset = false
    }
}
```

**EDIT ANSWER:** As stated in accepted answer Instead of adjusting the location of the UIView we choose to update the layout constraint dictating the UIViews location.  The following implementation of `keyboardWillShow`

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {
    if isKeyboardOffset == false {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            print("Keyboard show... \(keyboardSize)")
            self.topConstraint.constant -= 100

        }
        isKeyboardOffset = true
    }
}
```

Comment: So when you tap the first text field it behaves as expected. But when you tap the second while still selected on the first it moves up even higher? Or does it revert to the original before taping anything?

Comment: Use IQKeyboardManager

Comment: @CharlieFish Correct, on second tap it reverts to original, DOES NOT move up higher.  Select first textfield -> UIVIew moves up as expected -> Tap on 2nd (without unselecting first) -> UIVIew reverts to original frame.

Comment: @Jerland2 Any chance you could share some of your code for that section that is causing problems? Maybe just edit your question and let me know when you do. You could use IQKeyboardManager as well but it's sometimes nice to not use other libraries. So post your code and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani an entire 3rd party library seems overkill for one UIView that is semi problematic... Im hoping there is a more elegant solution that doesn't require a third party lib, thank you though

Comment: @CharlieFish relevant code added as requested.  It is perplexing to me because its some standard code i have used before...

Comment: @Jerland2 And when you click the first one then click the second one without dismissing what does the console print?

Comment: @Jerland2 And have you tried using breakpoints to see what is getting called?

Comment: @CharlieFish the console prints "keyboard show" when i select the second textfield.  NEVER calls keyboard hide though.  Also worth mentioning that even when i remove "isKeyboardOffset" and just try to move the frame every time "keyboardwillshow" is called the frame does NOT move on the second textfield select.  Edit: Yes i have tried breakpoints it is all called ,although it does not all react... meaning all loops/statements are hit the UI just isnt moving the second time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144111/discussion-between-charlie-fish-and-jerland2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Auto Layout with constraints on your view it automatically gets reset back to the original position. So instead of changing the view position if you change the value of the constraint this should work.